# Two pages with same url. How to crawl?

Tags: web-crawler, scrapy

I'll show my exact example, but I think it can be a problem for a general situation where you have to crawl one page whose url directs you to a different page.

The page I want to crawl goes under this url http://www.oxygenboutique.com/Shoes-All.aspx, but is not the page you get when you follow this link directly. The one I want is the one you see if you click in "SHOW ALL".

How can I get my spider to start in the one I want?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The "show all" Link is a call to a Javascript function on the webpage, and it is called like this:

```
__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$PGN01','')
```

My primary browser is Firefox, and it has excellent add-ons you can use.
I used the "Web Developer" add-on.

In tab that has the page, then do this:
Let the mouse cursor hovering over the show all link.
Then right-click and choose "Web Developer" > "Information" > "View Javascript   Alt+Shift+J"
Firefox will then open a new tab with all the Javascripts that page is using.

In the tab - a quick search finds the __doPostBack function, which is coded like this:

```
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
```

That JavaScipt function can be reduced to the JavaScript code below, if the test in the if-statemment evaluates to true, and we use the arguments from the call to to the function:

```
theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$PGN01';
theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = '';
theForm.submit();
```

Now we need to know what 'theForm' is.

The code below was found just above the __doPostBack function:

```
var theForm = document.forms['aspnetForm'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.aspnetForm;
}
```

From that we now know is that the 'theForm' is a reference to a 'form' HTML-tag, which has the id attribute 'aspnetForm' (id='aspnetForm'), which means that in the HTML document we shold look for something that begins like this:

```
<form id="aspnetForm"
```

To know how exactly that tag is written I will use the Firefox browser to look at modified HTML of the page you are interested in. 
**Here I am using the FireBug Add-on.**

The start-tag of the HTML form looks like this:

```
<form id="aspnetForm" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();"
 action="/Shoes-All.aspx" method="post" name="aspnetForm">
```

**So the action is using the same HTML document!**

Let us see  what the WebForm_OnSubmit() function is doing:

```
function WebForm_OnSubmit() {
    if (typeof(ValidatorOnSubmit) == "function" && ValidatorOnSubmit() == false)
        return false;
    return true;
```

}

Let us have a look at the ValidatorOnSubmit() function and an interesting variable it is using :

```
var Page_ValidationActive = false;

// ...

function ValidatorOnSubmit() {
    if (Page_ValidationActive) {
        return ValidatorCommonOnSubmit();
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

This means that the function will always return 'true', so we can now rewrite the form start-tag to:

```
<form id="aspnetForm" onsubmit="javascript:return true;"
 action="/Shoes-All.aspx" method="post" name="aspnetForm">
```

**From that we can conclude that the web page needs to be reloaded from the webserver.**

Now we need to know which variables and values that are used in the HTTP POST request.

To do that I had used Firefox again with JavaScript switched On. **Also, I am using the awesome Firebug Add-On.**
In The Form-element in the first div tag we find this:

```
<div>
    <input id="__EVENTTARGET" type="hidden" 
        value="" name="__EVENTTARGET">
    <input id="__EVENTARGUMENT" type="hidden" value="" name="__EVENTARGUMENT">
    <input id="__LASTFOCUS" type="hidden" value="" name="__LASTFOCUS">
    <input id="__VIEWSTATE" type="hidden"
        value="(lots of data here)" name="__VIEWSTATE">
</div>
```

If you you remember our previous reduced javascript code, it modified the value attribute of 2 input-tags in the form, so the HTML had been modfied by that function, so it really is:

```
<div>
    <input id="__EVENTTARGET" type="hidden" 
        value="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$PGN01" name="__EVENTTARGET">
    <input id="__EVENTARGUMENT" type="hidden" value="" name="__EVENTARGUMENT">
    <input id="__LASTFOCUS" type="hidden" value="" name="__LASTFOCUS">
    <input id="__VIEWSTATE" type="hidden"
        value="(lots of binary data here)" name="__VIEWSTATE">
</div>
```

You will of course need to do a verbatim copy of the content of the value attribute of the input-tag with the id "_VIEWSTATE".

FYI, Firefox say that the _VIEWSTATE input-tags XPath is:

```
 //*[@id="__VIEWSTATE"]
```

... and that its CSS selector is :

```
form#aspnetForm div input#__VIEWSTATE
```

After having downloaded all items from the webserver, you will then nedd to parse the HTML page.

The interesting content is embedded deep inside in the form.
It is a HTML table.

The relevant XPath for the table is:

```
//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dlList"]
```

... and the CSS selector is

```
table#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dlList
```

It contains a tbody, tr, td, div, and another table (=more bad design - someone needs to learn about table-less design. A HTML table will look horrible on smartphones and tablets.)

I think that at this point you should put the Beautiful Soup 4 parser on work.

Comment: After some time "studying" what you wrote, I understood that the button SHOW ALL just modifies the attribute "value" of hte input __EVENTTARGET of the form "aspnetForm", then submits it and so the html changes.

But I still don't understand why do I have to copy the content of the attribute value of the input "__VIEWSTATE", why do I have to download some items from the server. Basically I don't get how do make my spider parse this modified HTML, since it is not a link. (I'm pretty new to all of this and I have no idea if there is a way of crawling a modified HTML instead of a new given URL)